# How can I attach an event to the selection of Bootstrap collapsing panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

In the following code, there is a Bootstrap collapsible panel with no list, so it doesn't expand or contract. How can I attach an event to the selection of this panel?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="leftsidemenu">


<div class="panel-heading" id="aboutcollapsepanel">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseabout"  data-target="tabsabout" >About</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseabout" class="panel-collapse collapse">

                </div>



      </div>
</div>
```

My non-working attempt is as follows:

```
$("#aboutcollapsepanel").on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    alert("collapse panel activated");
});

$("#aboutcollapsepanel").on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
    alert("collapse panel deactivated");
});
```

How can I get the data-target value of the panel, in this case `tabsabout`, which is a jQueryUI tab widget. My goal is to get this id and pass it on to a javascript function that makes it visible, and that function has the signature `function performListItemAction(item)` where `item` would be the value of the data-target from the panel I click.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not adding onClick?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function performListItemAction(item) {
alert(item);
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="leftsidemenu">


<div class="panel-heading" id="aboutcollapsepanel">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseabout"  data-target="tabsabout" onClick="performListItemAction('tabsabout')">About</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseabout" class="panel-collapse collapse">

                </div>



      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're attempting. You just need to target `#collapseabout`. That's both the Bootstrap collapsible element, and the data-target. Then you can call performListItemAction() in the show handler.

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="leftsidemenu">
        <div class="panel-heading" id="aboutcollapsepanel" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseabout">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                About
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseabout" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                about content here..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/IvWxFtgoJo

Comment: I am trying to get a panel of jQueryUI tabs (with id `tabsabout` ) to appear on the screen through means of the `performListItemAction()` method. I think my confusion is arising from my understanding of the `data-target` attribute, because I see in your response its value refers to the submenu that expands when the main panel heading is clicked. However, in my case, there is no submenu to expand, and I want to send the id specified in `data-target` to the `performListItemAction()` method so that the jQueryUI tabbed panel can be displayed.

Comment: Maybe you can post a more complete example with your jQueryUI code? The Bootstrap collapse component alone can be used to toggle (show/hide) the panel I don't understand how jQueryUI is involved.

Comment: Basically I was trying to perform a method that would display a jQueryUI tabbed widget when the Bootstrap collapsible was clicked, on an area of the page different from the content area of the collapsible panel. I have received the answer now, thanks for the effort to help.